# HTML5shiv vs document.createElement (%html5tag%)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5shiv

Is there any difference amongst a robust (in a way) js  [`HTML5shiv`](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)  and just simple IE condition as such:?

```
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <script>
            document.createElement("main");
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: that is what the shiv does. Just saves you the time of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5shiv also adds 'default' styling to the elements (and a neat stylesheet).